# DataSnap Server as Windows Service and Debug

Tags: debugging, windows-services, datasnap

Good Morning,

We are just about to start a Multi-Tier project using DataSnap as our Server Application and Delphi Prism.

I made a little research and accepted the recomendation of creating the DataSnap Server as a Windows Service.

My question is: Is there an easy way to debug the DataSnap Server Service?

I'm asking that, because in some complex methods we may need to step into to validate the params values.

Sorry about my English, but I'm rusty because I haven't speak English for a long time.

**UPDATE:**

I almost forgot to update and explain how we get around this problem.

The only Alternative we found was to enable Log4Delphi in the DataSnap Server Project.
And set the log tool to register the SQL Queries and their params.

[Log4Delhpi](http://log4delphi.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Fro  debugging you set up a form based server and debug that one. When working ok, you reuse the units except the form and fire up.

Pawel Glowacki has a webinar about setting up a datasnap server with both a form and a service.

Comment: @AlfChristophersen can you give a link to that webinar ?

Comment: Here you have links both to Pawels webinar but also to others

https://www.google.no/?gws_rd=ssl#q=datasnap+server+service+forms+console